# Group ownership of a meeting in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is it possible to have a meeting in Outlook, which any member of a group can reschedule?

Or perhaps there is another type of calendar item, which can appear on a all group member's calendars and every one of them can change it?

Comment: It will help in formulating a response if you can tell us if you are you using an Exchange Server for your group?

Comment: @OSol1tair3 How can I discover that information?

Comment: If you are in a business environment and have an IT staff, then the odds are you are using an Exchange server. I would ask them.    Perhaps, it would help if you were a little more specific about the type of group.  Is this just an informal group of people with a common goal, or are you in an organized environment like a business, agency, .gov, etc.?

Comment: @OSol1tair3 Yes it's a business environment, I want to allow a small group (scrum team actually) to all be able to modify the time and duration of meetings. It's so annoying that only one person owns the meetings.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow other team members edit permissions to the calendar(s).

Alternatively, set up an shared mailbox and use that mailboxes calendar for the scrum meetings.

The third alternative is to ask your IT department whether they use resource calendars. If they do, then you could request one of those.

Comment: I contacted IT. I'll comment again when I have a result.